# How do you link classes in Slick2D?

Tags: java, class, slick2d

I am new to Slick2D and I am having problems linking classes. For example, in Slick2D you can't just make multiple classes and use the "implements" keyword. This results in all my code being crammed into a single class.

I have searched online for hours on how to do this in Slick2D, but I didn't get any helpful results. My question is, how do you make games using multiple classes in Slick2D?

Comment: What is your level in Java language? Your question is directly related to Java language more than Slick. The implements  keyword is only used for inheriting from a class not for using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Slick2D the same way you do it in a general Java Project.

After you called your AppStart method and your game thread is running you can create new objects inside your update, render or init method.

These classes can inherit from any class or implement any Interface.

Hope this helps.